# Where do you go to request new features in SSMS?

Tags: ssms

I'd like to ask Microsoft:

1. To color code the pages in SSMS based on the server they are connected to
2. Make it go ding when the query results are returned.

*Question:* How do you ask for those features?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should put your feature request on `feedback.azure.com`.

> https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server?query=ssms

Also you can tweet to `@sqltoolsguy` - Ken Van Hyning on Twitter.

Answer (score 54):

> 1. To color code the pages in SSMS based on the server they are connected to

In the registered servers pane, right-click on server, go to properties, then the connection properties tab. Select "custom color".

This is also visible in the connection dialog. Click options -> Connection Properties tab -> Use custom color (at the lower left).

> 2. Make it go ding when the query results are returned.

Tools | Options... | Query Results | Play the Windows default beep when a query batch completes.

---

The latest version of SQL Server Management Studio is available at [Download SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017).